# Angular JS - Resetting a dropdown with a function

Tags: angularjs

I have a listener set up in Angular to trigger an event when a select box's option changes.

I also have a button, which I want to "reset" the selection box to blank (NOT option 1).

Here's some code:

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown" ng-model="orderProp" >
  <option ng-repeat="cats in categories" value="{{cats}}">{{cats}}</option>
</select>
<button id="showHide" ng-click="showAll($event)" >Show all results</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.showAll = function($event){
    $scope.orderProp ="0";
}
```

Listener function on the select box:

```
   $scope.$watch( 'orderProp', function ( val ) {
        $scope.filteredMarkersProperty = $filter('filter')($scope.markersProperty, val);
        $scope.zoomProperty = 11;
        calcFocus();
    });
```

This KINDA works, although only sometimes, and I have no idea **why** it works (or doesn't) as I think it's the wrong way of going about it. I tried resetting it with jQuery `.prop('selectedIndex',0);`, but while this resets the index it doesn't trigger the listening function at all so this won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly doesn't work for you. Is it the `showAll` function, is it the $watcher function or is it the filtering or `calcFocus` function. Could you setup a plunker/jsfiddle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First - take a look at ngOptions in the select directive: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

```
<select ng-options="cats for cats in categories" ng-model="orderProps"></select>

<button ng-click="orderProps='0'">Show all results</button>
```

This will work as long as '0' is not one of the categories. The select-box will show a blank when the value of orderProps does not match any of the values in categories.

Your $watch function is not a listener on the select box, it watches orderProps and orderProps can get changed outside the select box. If you want a listener on the select box you could add a ng-change="myOnChangeFn()".

Added a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fqWkJBYOXGaYsK9Fnedc?p=preview

Comment: This is great, thank you, especially for the explanation about the $watch function, I didn't realise this!

Comment: How to make the same `orderProps='0'` effect from the controller ?