# reset the dropdown default value using ngOptions and selectpickerintable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Controller:-

```
var selecteduser = [];
$scope.dataList = [
{ id:1, fname: 'abc', lname: 'xyz' },
{ id:2, fname: 'xyz', lname: 'abc' },
{ id:3, fname: 'foo', lname: 'bar' }
]; 
$scope.addUser = function (user) {
   selecteduser.push(user); 
$scope.selectedItem = '';
}
```

HTML:-

```
<select class="dropdown" ng-model="selectedItem" 
ng-options =" data as data.fname +''+ data.lname for data in dataList" 
ng-change="addUser(selectedItem)">
</select>'
```

Here I reset the dropdown value after pushing the value in array. But it is not working $scope.selectedItem = '';. Anything I missed ? Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: Try setting it to null.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919520/angular-js-resetting-a-dropdown-with-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set selectedItem to null:

```
$scope.adduser = function (user) {
   if(user != null) 
        {
           selecteduser.push(user); 
           $scope.selectedItem = null;
        }
}
```

Here you go:

```js
var itemApp = angular.module("ItemApp", []);
itemApp.controller("ItemCtrl", function($scope){
     $scope.selecteduser = [];
     $scope.dataList = [
          { id:1, fname: 'abc', lname: 'xyz' },
          { id:2, fname: 'xyz', lname: 'abc' },
          { id:3, fname: 'foo', lname: 'bar' }
     ]; 
     $scope.addUser = function (user) {
        $scope.selecteduser.push(user); 
        $scope.selectedItem = '';
     } 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="ItemApp" data-ng-controller="ItemCtrl">

<select class="dropdown" ng-model="selectedItem" 
ng-options =" data as data.fname +''+ data.lname for data in dataList" 
ng-change="addUser(selectedItem)">
</select>

<hr />
Selected Users so far:
{{ selecteduser | json }}

</div>
```

Comment: $scope.selectedItem = null; is not working. Also I tried $scope.selectedItem =  '0' ; both is not working

Comment: what is selectpickerintable ?

Comment: Its my custom directive, I removed that one I edited my code, but still I have that problem

Comment: See the snippet.It works as expected. Also, I put 'selecteduser' onto $scope which wasn't the case before.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ng-change="addUser(selectedItem)">
```

In

```
ng-change="adduser(selectedItem)">
```